# Only the first error is shown when CRA project is built

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, react-scripts

In the default TypeScript based `create-react-app` project, only the first TS error is shown when the project is built with `react-scripts` but all errors are shown when running `tsc`.

The project was initialized with `create-react-app foo --typescript` and only `src/index.tsx` was modified after initialization:

*src/index.tsx*
    *src/index.tsx*

```
console.log(typeof nonExistentVar);
    console.log(typeof nonExistentVar);
console.log(typeof nonExistentVar2);
    console.log(typeof nonExistentVar2);
export {};
```

*package.json*

```
export {};
{


  "name": "foo",

  "version": "0.1.0",

  "private": true,

  "dependencies": {

    "@types/jest": "24.0.15",

    "@types/node": "12.6.8",

    "@types/react": "16.8.23",

    "@types/react-dom": "16.8.5",

    "react": "^16.8.6",

    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",

    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",

    "typescript": "3.5.3"

  },

  "scripts": {

    "start": "react-scripts start",

    "build": "react-scripts build",

    "test": "react-scripts test",

    "eject": "react-scripts eject"

  },

  "browserslist": {

    "production": [

      ">0.2%",

      "not dead",

      "not op_mini all"

    ],

    "development": [

      "last 1 chrome version",

      "last 1 firefox version",

      "last 1 safari version"

    ]

  }

}
```

*tsconfig.json*

```
{

  "compilerOptions": {

    "target": "es5",

    "lib": [

      "dom",

      "dom.iterable",

      "esnext"

    ],

    "allowJs": true,

    "skipLibCheck": true,

    "esModuleInterop": true,

    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,

    "strict": true,

    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,

    "module": "esnext",

    "moduleResolution": "node",

    "resolveJsonModule": true,

    "isolatedModules": true,

    "noEmit": true,

    "jsx": "preserve"

  },

  "include": [

    "src"

  ]

}
```

`npm start` shows only the first error:

```
Failed to compile.

C:/foo/src/index.tsx
TypeScript error in C:/foo/src/index.tsx(1,20):
Cannot find name 'nonExistentVar'.  TS2304

  > 1 | console.log(typeof nonExistentVar);
      |                    ^
    2 | console.log(typeof nonExistentVar2);
    3 | export {};
```

And `tsc` shows all errors at once:

```
src/index.tsx:1:20 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'nonExistentVar'.

1 console.log(typeof nonExistentVar);
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/index.tsx:2:20 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'nonExistentVar2'.

2 console.log(typeof nonExistentVar2);
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 2 errors.
```

---

How can I force `start` and `build` scripts to show all errors?

Comment: If compiler fails to find a variable named `nonExistentVar`, how is it supposed to proceed and show further errors? Because of it cannot find the variable, it failed to build and shows why it failed. It makes total sense to me to show only the first error.

Comment: *how is it supposed to proceed and show further errors* - raw `tsc` call allows that. I'm not sure how to do that, hence the question. My goal is to list all errors that need to be fixed on project build instead of fixing them one by one.

Comment: OK, sorry, I got it. I found [this](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript/issues/103#issuecomment-314756009) thread and then after some search found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dev-utils). Maybe these will give some clue.

Comment: I found this https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/67a2088a7b6ebbf6b78c82bb4b179d732340e2f2/packages/react-dev-utils/WebpackDevServerUtils.js#L226
However, turning off this logic didn't help out. You have to eject and tweak `scripts/build.js` file

Comment: @HarunYilmaz Thanks for the research, I'll give it a check.

Comment: gotta check `react-scripts`' `tsc` usage closely...

Comment: @amankkg Thanks for the link, it expains the cause. At this point I'm trying to avoid ejection if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a better solution. No forking or ejecting necessary. You can write a very simple plugin that hooks into `fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin` to get all the errors and print them. Edit `craco.config.js` to create the plugin class in my example I called it `PrintAllWebpackErrorsPlugin`. Then instantiate the class in the `webpack` section of the `module.exports`. Don't forget to reset `craco start` to apply the changes. The `craco.config.js` file should look something like the following:

```
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');
// This plugin uses a hook on the ForkTSCheckedWebpackPlugin to extract the errors and print them to console
class PrintAllWebpackErrorsPlugin {
    apply(compiler) {
        const hooks = ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin.getCompilerHooks(compiler);
        hooks.done.tap("PrintAllWebpackErrorsPlugin", function(errors) {
            errors.forEach(err => {
                console.log(err.file)
                console.log(`Typescript error in ${err.file}(${err.line},${err.character})`)
                console.log(`${err.message} TS${err.code}`)
            })
        })
    }
}

module.exports = {
    reactScriptsVersion: "react-scripts" /* (default value) */,
    style: {
        modules: {
            localIdentName: ""
        },
        css: {
            loaderOptions: { /* Any css-loader configuration options: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader. */ },
            loaderOptions: (cssLoaderOptions, { env, paths }) => { return cssLoaderOptions; }
        },
        sass: {
            loaderOptions: { /* Any sass-loader configuration options: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader. */ },
            loaderOptions: (sassLoaderOptions, { env, paths }) => { return sassLoaderOptions; }
        },
        postcss: {
        }
    },
    eslint: {
        enable: false /* (default value) */,
        mode: "extends" /* (default value) */ || "file",
        configure: { /* Any eslint configuration options: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring */ },
        configure: (eslintConfig, { env, paths }) => { return eslintConfig; },
        pluginOptions: { /* Any eslint plugin configuration options: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/eslint-webpack-plugin#options. */ },
        pluginOptions: (eslintOptions, { env, paths }) => { return eslintOptions; }
    },
    babel: {
        presets: [],
        plugins: [],
        loaderOptions: { /* Any babel-loader configuration options: https://github.com/babel/babel-loader. */ },
        loaderOptions: (babelLoaderOptions, { env, paths }) => { return babelLoaderOptions; }
    },
    typescript: {
        enableTypeChecking: true /* (default value)  */
    },
    webpack: {
        alias: {},
        plugins: {
            add: [
                // Notice I'm instantiating the plugin here to include it.
                new PrintAllWebpackErrorsPlugin(),
            ], /* An array of plugins */
            remove: [],  /* An array of plugin constructor's names (i.e. "StyleLintPlugin", "ESLintWebpackPlugin" ) */
        },
        configure: { /* Any webpack configuration options: https://webpack.js.org/configuration */ },
        configure: (webpackConfig, { env, paths }) => { return webpackConfig; }
    },
    jest: {
        babel: {
            addPresets: true, /* (default value) */
            addPlugins: true  /* (default value) */
        },
        configure: { /* Any Jest configuration options: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration */ },
        configure: (jestConfig, { env, paths, resolve, rootDir }) => { return jestConfig; }
    },
    devServer: { /* Any devServer configuration options: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver */ },
    devServer: (devServerConfig, { env, paths, proxy, allowedHost }) => { return devServerConfig; },
    plugins: [
        {
            plugin: {
                overrideCracoConfig: ({ cracoConfig, pluginOptions, context: { env, paths } }) => { return cracoConfig; },
                overrideWebpackConfig: ({ webpackConfig, cracoConfig, pluginOptions, context: { env, paths } }) => { return webpackConfig; },
                overrideDevServerConfig: ({ devServerConfig, cracoConfig, pluginOptions, context: { env, paths, proxy, allowedHost } }) => { return devServerConfig; },
                overrideJestConfig: ({ jestConfig, cracoConfig, pluginOptions, context: { env, paths, resolve, rootDir } }) => { return jestConfig },
            },
            options: {}
        }
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 4):

### The problem?

Here's what really happened. When [`fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin#installation) finds "type errors" in your code, it adds them to webpack's [compilation errors](https://github.com/TypeStrong/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin/blob/39fbffb8356f84981b1ff7853638bb8eee457643/src/index.ts#L916) for further processing and/or logging.

When the `start` script from [`react-scripts`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts) package is executed, the same errors array is [trimmed to length 1](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/cbad256a4aacfc3084be7ccf91aad87899c63564/packages/react-scripts/scripts/build.js#L171-L175). It then shows the first error (the only error) and [stops the process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57171785/only-the-first-error-is-shown-when-cra-project-is-built/57226138#comment100944691_57171785).

When the `build` script is run, it's the `react-dev-utils/WebpackDevServerUtils` that does the [same thing](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/cbad256a4aacfc3084be7ccf91aad87899c63564/packages/react-dev-utils/WebpackDevServerUtils.js#L224-L228) internally.

---

### The solution?

As pointed out by [@amankkg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57171785/only-the-first-error-is-shown-when-cra-project-is-built/57226138#comment100944691_57171785), "*you have to eject and tweak `scripts/build.js` file*" and the *build* process will work the way you want it to.

The real problem is with starting a dev server since `react-dev-utils/WebpackDevServerUtils` is a part of node_modules and tweaking it locally is not a long-term fix. Your best bet is to fork the repo on github, make the required changes and use your forked version in your project(s).

---

### Edit 1

Also, if you run the webpack config with just [`webpack-cli`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli), you'd see both the errors (along with a completed build).

Just eject the code, modify webpack's config file to set `webpackEnv` from `NODE_ENV`:

```
module.exports = function(webpackEnv) {
  webpackEnv = webpackEnv || process.env.NODE_ENV    //// add this line
  const isEnvDevelopment = webpackEnv === 'development';
  const isEnvProduction = webpackEnv === 'production';
```

and run the following:

```
npm i -g webpack-cli
NODE_ENV=development webpack --config config/webpack.config.js
```

Here's the sample output:

```
...

Entrypoint main = static/js/bundle.js ...

ERROR in /foo/src/index.tsx
ERROR in /foo/src/index.tsx(14,20):
TS2304: Cannot find name 'nonExistentVar'.

ERROR in /foo/src/index.tsx
ERROR in /foo/src/index.tsx(15,20):
TS2304: Cannot find name 'nonExistentVar2'.

...
```

---

### Edit 2

There is one more thing you could try. There's this node package [`patch-package`](https://github.com/ds300/patch-package) that allows patching node_modules code locally and commits the said patch to your repo. I haven't used it but the docs explain the process pretty neatly. You should definitely check it out.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to avoid the ejection if possible. I will likely resort to patch-package since this seems to be unfixable with react-app-rewired.